# What email format is used by CRM 2011 to validate email address?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Can anybody tell that how emailaddress is validated in CRM 2011 ?

Because when I am trying to save EmailAddress on Lead Entity

like

```cs
Lead lead = new Lead()
{
   FirstName = "ABC",
   LastName = "XYZ",
   EmailAddress1 = "test@test.com"
};
serviceProxy.Create(lead);
```

It throws `Generic SQL Error.` 
I think it is because `EmailAddress1` field has Format = `Email`.

I have created a new field `new_MyEmail` and set Format = `Email`

```cs
Lead anotherLead = new Lead()
{
   FirstName = "DEF",
   LastName = "STU",
   new_MyEmail = "test1@test.com"
};
serviceProxy.Create(anotherLead);
```

It also throws "`eneric SQL Error.`

Then I have deleted `new_MyEmail` field and re-created with Format = `text`.

It works..!!

So please if anybody can tell what is the reason of this or what is format of email address for CRM 2011, then would be great for me.

Thanks.

Comment: strange issue, first thing that I suggest is to use the `crmsvcutil.exe` from the latest SDK to generate again the C# class

Comment: yes I know that and I always do so

Comment: onpremise or online? rollup installed? tried with account or contact entities as well?

Comment: I am using onpremise and Update Rollup 12