# Single line of text - Email format option error

Tags: c#, plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm actually looking to update an account record and I get an error I never had previously.
My plugin is synchronal, on Post-upgrade.
Im retrieving my record using service retrieve, and everything is working fine, except if I updated an email field.
I get the following error:
Crm Exception: Message: Generic SQL error., ErrorCode: -2147204784, InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.EmailSearchBase' with unique index 'ndx_for_forward_update'.

Apparently I’m not alone to get this error but I haven’t find a solution yet.
Here is a post from an other user:
[What email format is used by CRM 2011 to validate email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136453/what-email-format-is-used-by-crm-2011-to-validate-email-address)

Thanks for your replies.

Best regards,
Gaëtan Fisse

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by retrieving the entity from the OrganizationService in the post-operation step. If you use the post-image instead of retrieving the entity, it will not lock the table.

Answer (score -1):

A row where emailid is already exists in the table dbo.EmailSearchBase. The unique index on emailid column is preventing you from committing another record with the same emailid.
either you remove this unique index constraint or first you remove that record from table with given emailid and then update your record with given emailid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187019.aspx